# How to add a colour circular border in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have rounded an image in html/css but now I want to add an border around that image. The only problem is that no border is showing.

**Here is my code** HTML

```
<img src="smiling.png" class = "roundedImage" style =width:20px;height:20px;>
```

**Here is the CSS code**

```
.roundedImage {

background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

border-width: 1px;
border-color: Black;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-border-radius:50px;
-moz-border-radius:50px;
border-radius:50px;
width:90px;
height:90px;

}
```

The image shows rounded but no colour border.

Answer (score 4):

For border you could do:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

And then you could remove these:

```
border-width: 1px;
border-color: Black;
```

Or just add (as pointed out by @Steve Sanders):

```
border-style: solid;
```

Comment: More specifically, they are missing `border-style`

Comment: Updating the answer with this.

Comment: Sorry none of that worked, I'm using jquery do you think that may changer anything?

Comment: Weird. I don't know if it could have something to do with jQuery. I would definitely guess not. Here's a fiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/r546fuxq/1/

Comment: Could it be that the border is just too small to be noticeable? Have you tried making it bigger just to check?

Comment: Yes 7px but no difference

Comment: @user3210416, this is a correct answer *to the question you actually asked*. If the border does not show up after this fix, you have *another* problem, and its cause is not in the code posted. Please accept this answer and ask a new question *with sufficient code* needed to actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey @user3210416, thank you for the up vote but selecting the answer as accepted would be great for me to get some rep too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick(not px but %):

```
.roundedImage {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;

}
```

And the border style has to be solid, otherwise you'll see no line at all :)

http://jsfiddle.net/4mezhws7/

Comment: Well, technically the style does not have to be solid. It can be e.g. `dotted`. The point is that it needs to be different from the initial value that is the default in most contexts, `none`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it to be that you have a space between 'class' and the equals sign. Space between the equal sign and the speech mark. A space between 'style' and the equal sign. Plus no speech marks around your style content and no back slash to end the img tag.

Finally, what I really think it is, is you need a border style.

```
Border-style: solid;
```

Comment: The first paragraph makes three incorrect notes about syntactic issues that are not related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your css just add `border-color: 1px solid black;` . This will give your border color